# "more" usage in the sentences from Longman dictionary

Tags: meaning

I looked up "more"
However, Which meaning does the under sentences have? I want to figure out it.
The sentences are from Longman dictionary.

1. used to say that something happens a greater number of times or for longer
2. used to say that something happens to a greater degree
3. some other meaning?

> • Our future competitiveness and prosperity depend more than ever before on technology and industry.

> • Visitors to the centre complained about the service more than last year.

> • Anthony needs to practise more than the other students, but he gets it right in the end.

Comment: You can also say "Our future competitiveness and prosperity **increasingly** depend on technology and industry."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our future competitiveness and prosperity depend **to a greater degree** than ever before on technology and industry.

*Visitors to the centre complained about the service more than last year.*
The word 'more' is in the wrong position. More visitors complained, or they complained more?

Anthony needs to practise **a greater number of times or for longer** than the other students, but he gets it right in the end.

Comment: I am sorry to tell you it is from Longman dictionary.

Comment: I am delighted to point out that it is under "Examples from the Corpus": not an example of perfect English but of colloquial English. People might understand the sentence to mean "more of the visitors complained than last year" or "the visitors complained to a greater degree". If the sentence began "more visitors" it would mean there were more complaints. If it said they "complained more" it would mean they complained to a greater degree.

Comment: Ah~ha! hmm maybe Longman dic is supposed to say "Visitors ~~ " sentence is about "-used to say that something happens to a greater degree". It is still ambiguous, though. Isn't it?

Comment: I can't understand your suggestion I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi I mean this sentence [Visitors to the centre complained about the service more than last year.] can be understood in two ways. One is  “more visitors” and another is “complained more. And in this sentence, <more> means -used to say that something happens to a greater degree.

Comment: I don't think the sentence "Visitors to the centre complained about the service more than last year." is ambiguous... The number of visitors is irrelevant and doesn't need to be mentioned. One can get more complaints with a lower/greater/same number of customers. The only fact I see here is that they have received more complaints/people complained more.